# Как склеить два массива по одинаковым значениям в один. PHP

Tags: php

Вопрос такой есть два массива

```
$arItems и $arProps1
```

Элементы первого массива  `$arItems`:

```
Array([0] => 1909) Array([0] => 1910)
```

Элементы второго массива `$arProps1`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2707
            [UF_VISITOR] => 1909         
            [UF_DRIVER] => 
            [UF_DRIVERS] =>            

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2708
            [UF_VISITOR] =>          
            [UF_DRIVER] => 1910
            [UF_DRIVERS] =>            

        )


)
```

Как присвоить значениям массива `$arItems` значения массива `$arProps1` в зависимости от наличия числа в элементе массива и объединить в один массив?

Хочу чтобы получилось так:

```html
Array(
    [0] => 2707 => Array( [2180] => Array(
                                     [ID] => 2707
                                     [UF_VISITOR] => 1909
                                     [UF_DELIVERY_CONTRACT] =>)
```

Comment: покажите какой результат вы хотите получить

Comment: надо искать число среди трех элментов `UF_*` ? они всегда по одному заполнены, или может быть и больше одного?

Comment: @teran гораздо больше и число элементов будет расти

Comment: @madfan41k Добавил желаемый результат.

Comment: Ответьте нормально на вопросы. Среди каких элементов выложенных массивов нужно искать совпадение. Ограничен ли список этих элементов. Может быть заполнен только один такой элемент, или несколько. Приведите полный пример исходных данных.

Comment: откуда в результате у вас `2180` вообще?

Comment: @teran там же написано "Хочу чтобы получилось так"  :))))))